# Finding a word in a range and inserting those cells that have the word into a column

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find a word in a range of cells and then copying the cells that have the word in another column.
for example the range of cells is

```
          A 
1   john see the man john
2   rain is the friend
3   john can teach
4   learn
5   learning those books
6   fred
7   continuing
8   learn john
9   see top
10  fresh verdic
```

I want to find the word "john" and copying those cells that contain john in column B:

```
        B
1  john see the man john
2  john see the man john
3  john can teach
4  learn john
```

My code doesn't work.

```
Sub find()
 Dim m_rnFind As Range
    Dim m_stAddress As String

    'Initialize the Excel objects.
    Set m_wbBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set m_wsSheet = m_wbBook.Worksheets("Book1")

    Set m_rnCheck = m_wsSheet.Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Retrieve all rows that contain john.  
    With m_rnCheck
        Set m_rnFind = .find(What:="john")
        i = 1
        If Not m_rnFind Is Nothing Then
            m_stAddress = m_rnFind.value
            Cells(i, 2).Value = m_stAddress

            Do

                Set m_rnFind = .FindNext(m_rnFind)
                i = i + 1
            Loop While Not m_rnFind Is Nothing And m_rnFind.Address <> m_stAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Edited since I missed the repeat necessity.

This worked on my quick test.

```
Sub find()
  Dim c As Range
  Dim destination As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Const SEARCH_TERM As String = "john"

  Set destination = Range("B1")
  For Each c In Range("A1:A10")
    i = 1
    Do While InStr(i, c.Value, SEARCH_TERM) > 0
        destination.Value = c.Value
        Set destination = destination.Offset(1, 0)
        i = InStr(i, c.Value, SEARCH_TERM) + Len(SEARCH_TERM)
    Loop
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but the problem is if there is two john in one cell, your code only see the first john, In that case, I want to copy that cell in two rows in column B, because the cell has two john.